# Puppet modules for installing ASP (not ASP.Net)?

Tags: windows, asp-classic, puppet

We have an old website that uses classic ASP for part of its functionality.  We're moving it to Windows 2012 and wanted to try puppetizing the process.  Are there puppet modules that will install classic ASP that we can use from the forge or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a great question. I'm going to guess that you have already searched both the forge and GitHub:

- https://forge.puppetlabs.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rank&q=asp
- https://github.com/search?q=puppet+asp&ref=reposearch&utf8=%E2%9C%93

I also looked around and I didn't see one. I think you are stuck with adding this in your own manifests/modules. However the process for installing ASP is really as simple as just enabling it in IIS.

#### DISM

You can get it by simply using the [puppetlabs-dism](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/dism) module with

```
# may require other items turned on as well with DISM
dism { "IIS-ASP":
  ensure => present,
}
```

**Note:** you may need other components installed with this, so you may need more checks.

### Windows Feature (Recommended)

For a more updated way of doing this, one should install the [windows modules pack](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/windows) although you can install just the [puppet-windowsfeature](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppet/windowsfeature) module.

```
  # add windows features
  # Ensure IIS itself is installed with management tools
  windowsfeature { 'Web-WebServer':
  installmanagementtools => true,
  } ->
  # Ensure ASP is enabled for IIS
  windowsfeature { 'Web-Asp':
  } ->
  # Optionally ensure ASP.NET 3.5 is enabled for IIS
  windowsfeature { 'Web-Asp-Net':
  } ->
  # Optionally ensure ASP.NET 4.5 is enabled for IIS
  windowsfeature { 'Web-Asp-Net45':
  }
```

The above is a bit above and beyond, but it shows what you may not have even considered, Puppet can handle installing and configuring IIS itself for you. The example for using the windows features module was pulled from the [chocolatey-chocolatey_server](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey_server) module - see https://github.com/chocolatey/puppet-chocolatey_server/blob/55b58e7869f0665c63e285749de13837f6748767/manifests/init.pp#L45-L69 and you will see you can also manage IIS sites and application pools using the [puppet-iis](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppet/iis) module.

Comment: And yes it is really that simple.

Comment: I wondered about DISM when going through the forge, but thanks for validating my suspicion-- and double thanks for the sample usage of the windowsfeature modules.  I'll put them to good use.